# How does XPath handle commas in element and attribute text?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm using commons configuration to read SQL queries from an XML file of my own design, the following are two slightly different examples of a query in a config file:

```
<query name="authenticateAccount" type="function">
    <sql>
        { ? = call account_authenticate(?, ?) }
        <parameter name="retun" type="java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN" direction="out" index="1" />
        <parameter name="supplied_email" type="java.lang.String" direction="in" index="2" />
        <parameter name="supplied_pw" type="java.lang.String" direction="in" index="3" />
    </sql>
</query>

<query name="authenticateAccount" type="function">
    <sql text="{ ? = call account_authenticate(?, ?) }">
        <parameter name="retun" type="java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN" direction="out" index="1" />
        <parameter name="supplied_email" type="java.lang.String" direction="in" index="2" />
        <parameter name="supplied_pw" type="java.lang.String" direction="in" index="3" />
    </sql>
</query>
```

The query text (seen in the sql element's text or "text" parameter above) is to be provided as a parameter to java.sql.Connection.prepareCall() to create a JDBC CallableStatement.

However, when that text is read by

```
// I tried both of these for the first xml example:
HeirarchicalConfiguration.getString("query[@name='authenticateAccount']/sql/text()")
HeirarchicalConfiguration.getString("query[@name='authenticateAccount']/sql")
// The following for the second xml example:
HeirarchicalConfiguration.getString("query[@name='authenticateAccount']/sql/@text")
```

Those XPath expression read the query text in right up to but excluding the first comma:

```
{ ? = call account_authenticate(?
```

Is what I see when displaying the text that's read in with the XPath expression.

I tried googling info on XPath expressions and commas in XML but found nothing helpful.  Why isn't the text being read past the first comma?

Comment: the first xml looks really fishy, the second one (`/sql/@text`) should parse just fine tough, probably a issue with the parser you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas are perfectly legal in an element's text or attribute values and XPath should select the entire string without splitting it in both cases, which points to an issue in your host environment.

Indeed, the documentation says that the comma is used as a default separator in Hierarchical Configurations:

> Lists of properties can be defined in a short form using the delimiter
>   character (which is the comma by default). In this example the
>   buttons.name property has the three values OK, Cancel, and Help, so it
>   is queried using the getList() method. This works in attributes, too.
>   Using the static setDefaultDelimiter() method of AbstractConfiguration
>   you can globally define a different delimiter character or - by
>   setting the delimiter to 0 - disabling this mechanism completely.
>   Placing a backslash before a delimiter character will escape it. This
>   is demonstrated in the pattern attribute of the numberFormat element.

**Source:** http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html#Accessing_properties_in_hierarchical_configurations

That document also has a section explaining why this feature was probably a bad decision and includes more specific details on disabling it. I'd suggest reading the entire thing.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I guess it didn't occur to me to check the commons configuration docs because I expected it to rely on XPath.  Why on earth would one need a facility like getList() to parse CSVs in a structured document?  If the data were meant to be a list, make a list-like structure!

Comment: The documentation seems out of date: the static method is AbstractConfiguration.setDefaultListDelimiter(char) http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractConfiguration.html#setDefaultListDelimiter(char)  And I'm not sure how they propose setting anything to 0 with a char parameter - using '0' actually delimits the list on the character '0'.